# Draw Image to form? (size related issue)

Tags: winforms, drawimage

I'm trying to draw a 400x400 px image to a 400x400 form that I made. What I'm doing is:

```
Graphics.DrawImage Method (Image, 0, 0, 400, 400) 0, 0, 400, 400, ...
```

But when I run the form, the image seems to stretch slightly upon the y-axis, the x-axis seems to be working correctly.

This was what I was doing before (stretching the old smaller images to fit the size)

```
... (Image, 0, 0, 264, 231) 0, 0, 400, 400, ...
```

or something like that. Now that I'm trying to do it the correct way, I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Edit: I wonder if using a simpler verson of Graphics.DrawImage would work? Although I still need to figure out what is wrong with what I'm doing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bit confusing what the issue is.  Are you trying to make a 264x231 image stretch into a 400x400 image?

Comment: No, That is what I was originally doing, but the image was stretched and since I went back and made the file (which is drawn to the form) a 400x400 image to match the form which is also 400x400, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Basic : Window size seems wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135118/visual-basic-window-size-seems-wrong)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a borderless form at 400 x 400, then it should be ok.

If not, then you have to account for the non-client dimensions of the form to reach the size you want.

You can just do this for drawing:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0)
```

To set your form size, you can try this:

```
Me.ClientSize = New Size(400, 400)
```

Comment: This might be the problem, I have just set the form to 400x400 and the image im drawing is 400x400, if the form borders count towards the total then this is probably the issue (sorry, fairly new with vb). If so, is their a way to scale it down better than in my example that I showed in the original question?

Comment: Me.Clientsize = New Size (400, 400) will set the actual form to 400x400 and then the surrounding border will go beyond that?

Comment: @user1041950 Yes, sort of.  The form size will be larger than 400 x 400 to accommodate the caption and borders, but the client size will match your image size.  On my machine, the form size became 408 x 427 when I change the ClientSize to 400 x 400.

Comment: I will try that out right now and see if it works! Thanks. -EDIT: I get a syntax error when I put the code in, where should it go? On load, on form? It says "me." is improper syntax.

Comment: Just kidding, needs to go in formload, I was being dumb. Thank you so much, exactly what I needed =D  Also we live in the same town.

Comment: @user1041950 Glad it's working.  BTW, get off my lawn!  Just kidding.  :-)

Comment: Just because you asked so nicely =D